# Normalization of Curve $x-y^n=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $X\subset \mathbb P^2$ be the curve (over $\mathbb C$) defined by $x-y^n=0$. We can view it as points of the form 
>   $$\{(x,\sqrt[n] x)\}$$
>   in $\mathbb A^2$ and then take closure in $\mathbb P^2$. Here $x$ takes all the $n$ roots. So it is natrual to consider points of the form 
>   $$\{([p:q],[1:\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q}:(\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q})^2:\ldots:(\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q})^{n-1}])\}$$
>   in $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^{n-1}$ defined by
>   \begin{cases}
> (x_1/x_0)^n=p/q\\
> x_1/x_0=x_2/x_1\\
> x_2/x_1=x_3/x_2\\
> \ldots\\
> x_{n-1}/x_{n-2}=x_{n-1}/x_{n-2}\\
> \end{cases}
>   We denote it by $X'$.

I want to show that:

> $X'$ is the normalization of $X$

It looks reasonable, and I have checked it is true for $n$ small. But is there some smart way to prove this for any $n$? And is there any intuitive way to explain this?

More generally, is it always true that we can normalize an arbitrary plane curve in this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Over which field is this and what does $\sqrt[n]{x}$ mean? Also, what does _"this way"_ mean when the curve is any other curve than $Z(x-y^n)$?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Sorry for not clear. Over $\mathbb C$, and $\sqrt[n] x$ means any $n$-root of $x$ (does not matter which one, as we will take all the roots).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain And by "this way" I mean the very naive generalization for curves of the form $\{(x,f(\sqrt[n]x))\}$. But now I see it is still a strong condition on curves (not arbitrary) and may not be very interesting. I am just curious is there any general approach like this to normalize a plane curve?

Comment: The way you put it however, your description of $X$ is probably wrong: If you are really considering $\{[y^n:y:1]\}$, it would be an open subset of $\Bbb P^2$ - and a smooth affine curve, hence normal. Its closure is not normal, but you need the third variable here.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Yes you are perfectly correct. Sorry for the inaccuracy. I have edited it.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Besides, I want to point out that this is the special case of my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812323/normalization-of-spectral-curves-via-eigenspaces-of-centralizers). It might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer is no, this will not yield the normalization of $X$; quite simply because $X'$ is not a curve unless $n=2$.

Let me illustrate for $n=5$. The homogenized equations are the following:
\begin{align*}
z x_2   &= x_1^2 \\
z^2 x_3 &= x_1^3 \\
z^3 x_4 &= x_1^4 \\
z^4 x_0 &= x_1^5
\end{align*}
Now at any point with $z=x_1=0$, i.e. $p=[0:x_0:0:x_2:x_3:x_4]$, we have $p\in X'$. This means $\Bbb P^3\subseteq X'$ and consequently, $\dim(X')\ge 3$. It should be quite easy to see that $\dim(X')\ge n-1$ holds in the general case.

---

That said, I thought it beneficial to remark that there *is* a deterministic way to normalize a curve through successive blow-up operations and it might be a good idea to go through this process for the curve $z^{n-1}x-y^n$ and see what happens. This procedure is well-understood theoretically and algorithmically.

You should familiarize yourself with the theory first, but if you are interested in concrete computations, I recommend to play around with singular's [resolve](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_1458.htm) function in their online interface;

https://www.singular.uni-kl.de:8003/

For example, the code

```
LIB"resolve.lib";
LIB"reszeta.lib";
ring R=0,(x,y,z),dp;
ideal I=z6x-y7; 
list L=resolve(I);
presentTree(L)
```

will suggest that the curve can be desingularized by $n-2$ blowups. It might be a good exercise to try and prove that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I just found I described my question in a wrong way: $X'$ should not be in $\mathbb P^n$, but in $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^{n-1}$. I have edited the question. (Again, very sorry about this...)

Comment: Dear @Akatsuki, please do not take this the wrong way, but I think you should take a little more time to challenge and ponder your conjectures by yourself. I also still think you can benefit from the second part of my answer; desingularization of curves is well understood, why not study it in this classical way for your curve? It might be a more efficient way to obtain a concrete description for the normalization than your current approach.

Comment: By the way, in your edited question, set $x_0=0$ and $x_1=0$ and you will find that $X'$ is still not a curve.

Comment: Yes I have seen that also... thank you for your post and advice.

Comment: But are there some equations to describe the curve $\{([p:q],[1:\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q}:(\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q})^2:\ldots:(\sqrt[n] \frac{p}{q})^{n-1}])\}$? If you look at this parametric equation, the points $([p,0],[0,0,x_2,\ldots, x_n])$ can only be $([1,0],[0,0,\ldots,0,1])$

Comment: Seems certainly we can add some equations to describe it. Then my original question still makes sense.

Comment: I have edited the right equations to describe the curve. This time I am pretty sure it is correct :)